# icheck.js and Meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to integrate [iCheck](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/) on an Meteor app. Have anyone a clue how to integrate another JS libraries on Meteor apps?.

Comment: Adding the script to `public` directory should work

Comment: Can also put it in `client/lib` if the API exposes itself with a globally scoped variable

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did.

I added the js file (jquery.icheck.min.js) to client/lib to make it load first then I put the css (skins folder) in the public/ folder at the app root.

In order to load the skin (css files) I added this line to the app.html at the `<head>`

```
 <link href="/skins/minimal/blue.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To initialize the iCheck on my controls I put this function on Template rendered function:

```
Template.dataForm.rendered = function(){
  if(!this._rendered) {
    $('input').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-blue',
      increaseArea: '20%'
    });
  };
```

and voila.

Comment: if the css is in the right scope (client) you shouldn't need to make the include.