# iCheck.js in Meteor 0.9.1.1

Tags: jquery, meteor, icheck

I've implemented iCheck in Meteor 0.9.1.1 in the following way:

[icheck.js and Meteor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932883/icheck-js-and-meteor-app/25844874#25844874)

But Firebug tells me, that .iCheck is not a function.

I've just added jQuery with

```
Meteor add jquery
```

so I think I have the newest version of it, which should provide .iCheck. Or does it use an older version of jQuery?

Comment: Have you put iCheck js and css files in client/lib as advised in the SO answer ? You don't need the link tag in the head section BTW, any .css under the client dir will be automatically added to your app. You can remove the if(!this._rendered) part in the initialization code of the rendered callback too, it's not relevant anymore.

Comment: ok, thx, for this advice, but Firebug still tell me this: "Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: $(...).iCheck is not a function"

Comment: Shall I define iCkeck in my icheck.js file like `iCheck = function($) {` or change it back to `(function($) {` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I got it working :

1. Download and uncompress `iCheck-master` from the github repository.
2. Copy `icheck.js` to `client/lib/`
3. Copy the css of the theme you want in `client/config/` (example : `skins/flat/red.css`)
4. Copy the images of the theme you want in `public/img/icheck/` (example : `skins/flat/red.png`, `skins/flat/red@2x.png`)
5. Edit the css to reference properly the images (example : replace `red.png` with `/img/icheck/red.png`

Once this is done you can now use `iCheck` in your app like this :

`client/views/icheck-test/icheck-test.html`

```
<template name="icheck_test">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo">
    Foo
  </label>
</template>
```

`client/views/icheck-test/icheck-test.js`

```
Template.icheck_test.rendered=function(){
  this.$("input").iCheck({
    checkboxClass: "icheckbox_flat-red",
    radioClass: "iradio_flat-red"
  });
};
```

This process can be repeated for integrating nearly any jQuery plugin in Meteor.
We could also use a package but at the moment customizing the package to pick a specific theme is a bit tricky.